# Matlab can't see a specific function when running in parallel

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, matlabpool

This has got me stumped.

I've written a function `parObjectiveFunction` that runs several simulations in parallel using `createJob` and `createTask`. It takes as an argument an `objectiveFunction` which is passed deeper into the code to calculate the objective function value for each simulation.

When I run `parObjectiveFunction` from the directory where `objectiveFunction` is found, it works as expected, but when I go one level up, it can no longer find `objectiveFunction`. The specific error I get is

```
Error using parallel.Job/fetchOutputs (line 1255)
An error occurred during execution of Task with ID 1.

Error in parObjectiveFunction (line 35)
    taskoutput = fetchOutputs(job);

Caused by:
    Error using behaviourObjective/getPenalty (line 57)
    Undefined function 'objectiveFunction' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

(behaviourObjective is an object)

This is weird for several reasons.

`objectiveFunction` is definitely in `path`, and when I try `which objectiveFunction`, it points to the correct function. 
I have other components of the deeper code in other directories, and they are found without issue (they are objects rather than functions, but that shouldn't make a difference).
There's a line of code in `parObjectiveFunction` that runs the simulation, and when I run that directly in the matlab command window it finds `objectiveFunction` without issue.
I get the same results on my local machine and an HPC server.

My first thought was that the individual task might have its own `path` which didn't include `objectiveFunction`, but then that should cause problems for the other components (it doesn't). The problem is compounded because I can't work out how to debug the parallel code.

1. What am I doing wrong? Code that produced the issue is below.
2. Are there any known issues where matlab can't find functions when
   using parallel processing with `createJob`, `createTask`, `submit`
   and `fetchOutputs`?.
3. How can you debug in matlab when the issue is
   only when operating in parallel? None of my print statements appear.

---

To make something work for external testing would take quite a bit of hacking, but for the sake of the question, the parallel function is:

```
function penalty = parObjectiveFunction(params, objectiveFunction, N)

    % Takes a vector of input parameters, runs N instances of them in parallel
    % then assesses the output through the objectiveFunction

    n = params(1);
    np = params(2);
    ees = params(3);
    ms = params(4);
    cct = params(5);
    wt = params(6);
    vf = params(7);

    dt = 0.001;
    bt = 10;

    t = 10;


    c = parcluster;
    job = createJob(c);


    testFunction = @(run_number)behaviourObjective(objectiveFunction,n,np,ees,ms,cct,wt,vf,t,dt,bt,run_number);


    for i = 1:N

        createTask(job, testFunction, 1, {i});

    end

    submit(job);
    wait(job);
    taskoutput = fetchOutputs(job);

    pensum = 0;
    for i = 1:N
        pensum = pensum + taskoutput{i}.penalty;
    end

    penalty = pensum/N;

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to attach some additional files to your `job`. You can see which files were picked up by MATLAB's dependency analysis by running [`listAutoAttachedFiles`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/listautoattachedfiles.html), i.e.

```
job.listAutoAttachedFiles()
```

If this isn't showing your `objectiveFunction`, then you can manually attach this by modifying the [`AttachedFiles`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.job.html) property of the `job`.

It seems as though `objectiveFunction` is a `function_handle` though, so you might need to something like this:

```
f = functions(objectiveFunction)
job.AttachedFiles = {f.file}
```

Comment: Thanks, that has fixed the problem. It seems there is more going on under the hood to make parallelisation work that I was aware.

Comment: Glad that sorted it for you. We do try to make everything work "as if by magic" - but sometimes the magic fails, and you need to give the system some hints...